# Delete all files but keep all directories in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to do something which is probably very simple, I have a directory structure such as:

```
dir/
    subdir1/
    subdir2/
        file1
        file2
        subsubdir1/
            file3
```

I would like to run a command in a bash script that will delete all files recursively from dir on down, but leave all directories. Ie:

```
dir/
    subdir1/
    subdir2/
        subsubdir1
```

What would be a suitable command for this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

`find` lists all files that match certain expression in a given directory, recursively. `-type f` matches regular files. `-print0` is for printing out names using `\0` as delimiter (as any other character, including `\n`, might be in a path name). `xargs` is for gathering the file names from standard input and putting them as a parameters. `-0` is to make sure `xargs` will understand the `\0` delimiter.

`xargs` is wise enough to call `rm` multiple times if the parameter list would get too big. So it is much better than trying to call sth. like `rm $((find ...)`. Also it much faster than calling `rm` for each file by itself, like `find ... -exec rm \{\}`.

Answer (score 10):

With GNU's `find` you can use the `-delete` action:

```
find dir -type f -delete
```

With standard `find` you can use `-exec rm`:

```
find dir -type f -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 8):

```
find dir -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

where *dir* is the top level of where you want to delete files from

Note that this will only delete regular files, not symlinks, not devices, etc. If you want to delete everything except directories, use

```
find dir -not -type d -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: It depends on the shell, really. "Brace expansion" can happen in new bash or zsh. That's why I am always escaping them.

Answer (score 8):

```
find dir -type f -exec rm '{}' +
```

Comment: The `-exec` command can be terminated in two ways: with a semicolon or a plus sign. If you use a semicolon, then a new process is spawned for every single file. If you use a plus sign, then only one process is spawned. (Well, actually, if the commandline gets too long, then multiple processes are spawned – basically, it works like `xargs` but without all the quoting problems.) Say, you have two files, called A and B. Then, with semicolon two processes would be spawned: `rm A` and `rm B`. With plus, only one process gets spawned: `rm A B`.