# Recursively remove files

Tags: linux, bash

Does anyone have a solution to remove those pesky ._ and .DS_Store files that one gets after moving files from a Mac to A Linux Server?

specify a start directory and let it go? like /var/www/html/ down...

Comment: Although it's not a duplicate IMO, you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280429/delete-all-files-but-keep-all-directories-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Although not what you are asking. I would argue this is a better solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9665/create-tar-archive-of-a-directory-except-for-hidden-files

Answer (score 177):

change to the directory, and use:

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
find . -name "._*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Not tested, try them without the xargs first!

You could replace the period after find, with the directory, instead of changing to the directory first.

```
find /dir/here ...
```

Comment: I know his question didn't ask for it, but I can never remember: does your example handle filenames with spaces?

Comment: Yes, that is what the print0 and the -0 to xargs is for. Normally it wouldn't handle spaces correctly, however with print0 it will print the filename with a null character at the end of the line, which xarg with -0 will then use to pass the full path to xargs without a chance of having the whitespace being used a second or third parameter to the rm command which could be really bad!

Comment: @X-Istence - This wont recursively traverse sub-directories though right?

Comment: @X-Istence - What do you think about running this starting at /var/www/html and directories below it in a CRON say every hour? This box is a webserver, but files are uploaded frequently.

Comment: @X: newer findutils supports a `-delete` action, which could shorten this.  @JT: This searches recursively under `.`.  Depends on how many files and subdirectories there are... can't you just just forbid those from being uploaded?

Comment: @JT: It will recurse. `man find`. Using this in a cron would be possible, rather see if your FTPD supports upload scripts, which will check what is uploaded and remove files like  ._ and .DS_Store.

@ephemient: Yes, newer find will, however last time I used find it was not available. Also, I do believe there is a performance penalty to have find run the delete, as searching a directory and removing files at the same time can cause slowdowns (UFS has issues with this  from experience)

Comment: Using the `-r` (recursive) flag is not recommended in this case since you don't want to delete any directories..

Comment: +1 for "try them without the xargs first!" :) did what I needed flawlessly.

Comment: `.DS_Store` is not a directory, so there's no need for the `-r` flag on that line.  I'm not sure why you'd want `-f` either, since you'll only get file paths passed to `rm` that actually exist, so you don't need to suppress error messages.

Comment: @iconoclast: Possibly because some [moron](http://superuser.com/questions/384769/alias-rm-rm-i-considered-harmful) put `alias rm="rm -i"` into `.bashrc` (or `/etc/bashrc`). Yes, I've used systems that had that "feature" set up by default.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: good point.  Wouldn't `command rm` be a better (that is, more direct) solution? (By "direct" I mean it deals specifically with the problem at hand and nothing else, and therefore is less likely to have any unwanted side-effects, and is also going to be more self-explanatory to anyone who has to maintain the code later.)

Answer (score 93):

```
find /var/www/html \( -name '.DS_Store' -or -name '._*' \) -delete
```

Answer (score 93):

Newer findutils supports `-delete`, so:

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete
```

Add `-print` to also get a list of deletions.

Command will work for you if you have an up-to-date POSIX system, I believe. At least it works for me on OS X 10.8 and works for others who've tested it on macOS 10.12 (Mojave).

Credit to @ephemient in a comment on @X-Istence's post (thought it was helpful enough to warrant its own answer).

Comment: Works back in OSX 10.6 as well.

Comment: Cleanest and simplest solution, +1!

Comment: @OneOfOne: as my comment says, I got this from @ ephemient. As a beginner to bash, I found your (perhaps more correct) solution far less readable and usable. They may be functionally identical but I find this syntax provides more clarity.

Comment: The '.' isn't necessary because `find` recurses into the current working directory by default.

Comment: *In newer versions of the program, the directory may be omitted, and it will imply the current working directory* ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find)).  You still need `.` on macOS 10.12 (Sierra).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Indeed the cleanest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 19):

Simple command:

```
rm `find ./ -name '.DS_Store'` -rf
rm `find ./ -name '._'` -rf
```

Good luck!

Comment: This works great. BUT a word of caution, I just used this `rm -i `find ./ -name '*py'` -rf`, which did NOT prompt me to delete files. you will need to take it on the end (i.e. `-rfi`). Thank god for my backup script.

Comment: If there are too many files this breaks with the error: `-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long`

Answer (score 12):

```
cd /var/www/html && find . -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
cd /var/www/html && find . -name '._*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: I liked this one better simply because the "rm" doesn't have "-r" which isn't necessary for this specific task.

Answer (score 6):

You could switch to zsh instead of bash.  This lets you use ** to match files anywhere in a directory tree:

```
$ rm /var/www/html/**/_* /var/www/html/**/.DS_Store
```

You can also combine them like this:

```
$ rm /var/www/html/**/(_*|.DS_Store)
```

Zsh has lots of other features that bash lacks, but that one alone is worth making the switch for.  It is available in most (probably all) linux distros, as well as cygwin and OS X.

You can find more information on the [zsh site](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: A possible problem: since you don't use xargs, you might run into the command-line argument length restriction.  Also, Bash 4 supports `**` too :-) (though not by default, `shopt -s globstar` needs to be set)

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name "FILE-TO-FIND"-exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Using exec for each file found is not fast. It is faster to have find print them out and then use xargs to invoke rm once.

Comment: However, if you have a `find` that supports it, `+` is xargs-like: `find . -name "FILE-TO-FIND" -exec rm -rf {} +` - (also, you're missing a space before `-exec`)

Comment: we never had xargs in my day. And we had to walk to school, uphill both ways .......

Answer (score 3):

Example to delete "Thumbs.db" recursively;

```
find . -iname "Thumbs.db" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Validate by:

```
find . -iname "Thumbs.db"
```

This should now, not display any of the entries with "Thumbs.db", inside the current path.

Comment: Please be sure your answer prints a list of what's being deleted and explain why someone might want to use `xargs` and `print0` instead of `exec` (there are reasons).

Answer (score 3):

It is better to see what is removing by adding -print to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017322/886607)

```
find /var/www/html \( -name '.DS_Store' -or -name '._*' \) -delete -print
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have Bash 4.0++

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in /var/www/html/**/.DS_Store /var/www/html/**/._ 
do
 echo rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: Running a new copy of rm for each file is wasteful.

Comment: @X-Istence premature optimization is wasteful

Comment: Upvoted for originality and use of more recent bash innovations.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

'-delete' is not recursive.  So if .TemporaryItems (folder) has files in it, the command fails.

There are a lot of these pesky files created by macs:
.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
.TemporaryItems
.apdisk

This one command addresses all of them.  Saves from running find over and over again for multiple matches.

```
find /home/foo \( -name '.DS_Store' -or -name '._.DS_Store' -or -name '._*' -or -name '.TemporaryItems' -or -name '.apdisk' \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

`sudo rm -rf 2018-03-*`

here your deleting files with names of the format 2018-03-(something else)

keep it simple

Comment: You don't explain when someone might want to prefix a command with `sudo` nor do you provide any information how `rm` works in the context of your answer.