# How to recursively remove emacs backup files?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs, while in Dired mode, I can use the ~ command to mark all my emacs backups for deletion.  Is there a way to mark them all recursively so I can delete all my backups in the current directory and all subdirectories?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016844/bash-recursively-remove-files

Comment: I'd kind of like to do it from within Emacs.  Sometimes, I'm stuck using Windows and I don't always have bash/find, etc available.  My workflow would improved if I could simply do it in emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two kinds of dired: flat and recursive. For example:

```
(defun op-i:dired (rec)
  "customized dired: will display directory recursively when called with an argument"
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((dir (car (find-file-read-args "Dired: " nil))) 
        (opts (if rec (read-string "options: " "-lhAR") "-lhA")))
    (if (file-directory-p dir) (dired dir opts))))

(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "C-x C-d") 'op-i:dired)
```

Then calling this function with `C-u C-x C-d` will display dired recursively and with `C-x C-d` will do it as usual.

After displaying dired recursively you can delete backups or do other stuff recursively too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a *nix or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you should be able to do

```
find -name '*~' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Forgot the dot!. Otherwise I like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-name-dired` with file pattern `*~` to list only the backup files in a dired buffer.

Comment: An `M-x` answer is perfect for the OP.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on my Windows PC.  Do I need to configure something additional?

Comment: Ah, my apologies; that also needs a Unix-style `find` installed on Windows PCs.