# Remove all backup files in Linux using Shell script recursively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

How can I remove all backup files, i.e files ending with `~`, recursively in a particular folder in Ubuntu?

A script in any programming language would do.

Comment: [Existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016844/bash-recursively-remove-files)

Answer (score 18):

For one, you could use a simple `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
find folder -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Basically, look at "man find"

Answer (score 0):

First off, what do you mean by recursively? Recursion is a convenient way to implement dome algorithms, but tends to be over-used - but some people also apply the term to searching a directory tree (which can be implemented by other means that recursion). If you simply want to delete all files matching a specific glob in a directory tree then....

```
find /base/directory/ -type f -iname '*~' -exec rm -f {}\;
```

(but you might want to experiment with `find /base/directory/ -type f -iname '*~' -exec ls -l {}\;` first).