# How do you gitignore all single file extension files from a git repository after committing?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I'm new to using git and was wondering how do I remove all cached `.exe` files from a git repository (I want to keep them in my working folder). The root folder has subfolders that also have the `.exe` files.
Will the following command work or do I have to do something else? I understand the -r is for removing directories and not files and it just seems wrong, and on searching about this topic, only relevant thing I found was using `find` and `delete` commands, but I'm not sure about how to use them.

```
git rm --cached -r *.exe
```

Edit: I ran the command and it only removed the .exe from root folder not the sub folders
Is manually listing all sub folder paths and running that command the only option?

Since passing the git command with it's cached flag is required, for people who are unfamiliar with chaining commands in linux/ unix, the recursive remove unix answer is not sufficient.

Comment: That command looks fine to me, [-r](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt--r) is for recursiveness which is what you are after. The question in your title does not match the actual question though

Comment: I did not make a `.gitignore` before committing and well only option at that point is removing those files from the cache, which effectively is gitignoring them after commit, but I understand how it might not seem related? And the command did not remove files from sub folders only root

Comment: What shell are you using? Works for me

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Git Bash (I'm on windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively remove files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016844/recursively-remove-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+remove+files+recursively

Comment: `shopt -s globstar && rm **/*.exe`

Comment: @phd it answers parts of the question, but I don't want to remove files from my directory, only from the git repo, I'm also new to linux commands so where the git with rm --cached would go, I'm not sure I will learn with time though. and I have it mentioned in my body of the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (in an `sh` compatible shell):

```
find . -name '*.exe' -exec git rm --cached '{}' \;
```

Alternatively, less elegant but easier to compose:

```
ls -R | grep '.exe$' | xargs git rm --cached
```

The trouble with your `git rm -r` command is that it will only recurse into directories whose name ends with `.exe`, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Years of experience, I'm afraid. It helps to know what tools are available and what each of them can do. At first you have to read their manpages to find out how to use them, but eventually you learn the most common options by heart. Then you just put the building blocks together.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the wildcard so Git sees it rather than your shell:

```
git rm -n --cached \*.exe
```

(then rerun without the `-n` if you like what you see)